# How do I get thumbnails with captions to the right vertically aligned to the center on bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a website that uses Bootstrap 3 and I need a row with 3 columns of thumbnails with their captions to the right. Like this:

[image]

So my questions are:

- How do I get the captions to the right?
- How do I vertically center the text to the thumbnail?
- If possible I'd like to have the gray wrapper you see on the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to support IE8 or less you can use the following rule:

```
.vertical-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This should be applied to the child you want to vertical center inside its parent.

[source](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing thats for the text vertical align inside the thumbnail. That leaves the first question unanswered though.

Comment: You can put both the img tag and the tag containing the text inside a div (child of the column container) with this class assigned